# Activity lifecycle issue - upgraded to 4.0.3

Tags: android

I have all activities inherit from my BaseActivity. It's been working great for a year. Now after I upgraded my Nexus S to 4.0.3 my app stopped working - I get infinite loop that look like so:

```
12-28 20:09:22.285: DEBUG/IDATT.HomeActivity(24662): onCreate
12-28 20:09:22.285: DEBUG/IDATT.BaseActivity(24662): onCreate
12-28 20:09:22.442: DEBUG/IDATT.HomeActivity(24662): onResume
12-28 20:09:22.442: DEBUG/IDATT.BaseActivity(24662): onResume
12-28 20:09:22.578: DEBUG/IDATT.HomeActivity(24662): onCreate
12-28 20:09:22.578: DEBUG/IDATT.BaseActivity(24662): onCreate
12-28 20:09:22.653: DEBUG/IDATT.HomeActivity(24662): onResume
12-28 20:09:22.653: DEBUG/IDATT.BaseActivity(24662): onResume
12-28 20:09:22.785: DEBUG/IDATT.HomeActivity(24662): onCreate
12-28 20:09:22.785: DEBUG/IDATT.BaseActivity(24662): onCreate
12-28 20:09:22.863: DEBUG/IDATT.HomeActivity(24662): onResume
12-28 20:09:22.863: DEBUG/IDATT.BaseActivity(24662): onResume
```

So, when `HomeActivity` started it calls base.onCreate which is second line.
Then `onResume` called and for some reason after that - BaseActivity.onCreate called again.

Does this make sense? One thing I noticed is that everything runs OK until I turn screen. Then it starts blinking. Even if I hit Home and open application again. But if I kill process and restart it looks good until I try to flip screen again..

EDIT: I removed all the code samples - they not relevant.
Seems like I found my issue. I did override `onConfigurationChange` in my `Application`

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onConfigurationChanged");
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        //reset locale to our defined locale in settings
//        String l = Preferences.getLocale(getApplicationContext());
//        Locale locale = new Locale(l);
//        if (!l.equals(""))
//        {
//            newConfig.locale = locale;
//            Locale.setDefault(locale);
//            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
//        }
    }
```

Commented code caused issue. Seems like doing what I did (to change locale) caused whole UI to restart and it was doing it repeatedly. Now I need to come up with better way.

So, there is breaking change in this Locale area in 4.0

Comment: Show your `onCreate(...)` and `onResume()` code of both `BasActivity` and `HomeActivity`.

Comment: There is a lot of code, I tried commenting most of it with no change..

Comment: I've never used `updateConfiguration(...)` but that suggests to me it's going to trigger `onConfigurationChanged(...)`. No? If it does, that's where your infinite loop is coming from. What happens if you leave the call to `updateConfiguration(...)` commented out, uncomment the other lines and move `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);` to the end of your overridden `onConfigurationChanged(...)` method. In other words, call it last after you have modified `newConfig` to set its locale.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. But this issue just now started with 4.0 This code is bad anyway. I will try to see if I can get rid of it alltogether.

Comment: OK - sorry I can't help further. As I said, it's not something I've done in any of my own code. Good luck in finding a solution.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm experiencing the same now.

Comment: Yes, it is in main post

Comment: A better solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406345/activity-is-blinking-after-locale-change-in-android-4-1

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit AndroidManifest.xml and add android:configChanges="locale" for all activities. It can fix the re-create problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me but I found a solution here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406345/activity-is-blinking-after-locale-change-in-android-4-1

Answer (score 0):

android:configChanges="locale" saved me some real pain. I was getting an endless pause/resume loop but only on pre ics devices, and only after i downloaded the sdks for jellybean.