# WebView language error Android N

Tags: android, webview, android-7.0-nougat

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398528/android-webview-locale-changes-abruptly-on-android-n) question asked before about the WebView being broken in Android N especially with localization. I have another problem which I cannot figure out how to fix.

As shown in [image: this] pic, I have two languages set on my Pixel device running 7.1.1. Now, I'm trying to load the following url in a WebView in my app.

```
"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?<my-params>"
```

What I notice is that the page loads in Chinese instead of English which is my current Locale language. I tried opening the above link on my Chrome desktop (where I am signed in with the same account as my phone) and it loads in Chinese too! I went to Chrome's settings to find that they language preferences are saved to my account because they show up in [image: Chrome] too.

I did try setting locale before `setContentView()` in my app like this:

```
public static void setLocale(Locale locale){
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setLocale(locale);
    Context context = MyApplication.getInstance();
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

but in vain. If I put a log statement, it prints the correct `Locale` which is `en-US`. The `WebView` still loads the page in Chinese though. Any thoughts on how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is affected by the webview in the Android N.

- On the first launching of the webview, it resets the locale to default.
- If you then rotate the phone - the locale gets correctly set back to the custom locale.
- If you then launch the webview again - the locale stays correct.

To fix this, you have to switch back to your chosen language after the page was loaded.

You may also check on the Activity/Fragment life cycle when to switch language.

Sources:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37113860
https://gist.github.com/amake/0ac7724681ac1c178c6f95a5b09f03ce#new-locales-vs-old-locales-chinese
[Activity is blinking after locale change in Android 4.1+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406345/activity-is-blinking-after-locale-change-in-android-4-1)

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround fixed it in my case.
Just create unused dummy WebView at the beginning of the main Activity onCreate().

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        webViewLocalesBugWorkaround()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    // etc.
}

private fun webViewLocalesBugWorkaround() {
    val webView = WebView(this)
}
```